# What are the double set triggers for?

Tags: quigley-down-under

In [Quigley Down Under (1990)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102744/?ref_=nv_sr_2) there is a scene where Quigley displays his capabilities of long range shooting with his rifle by shooting a bucket. In the scene, Quigley describes his weapon.

> **Marston**: The legendary Sharp.
>   **Quigley**: You know your weapons. It's a lever-action breech loader. Usual barrel length's 30 inches. This one has an extra four. It's converted to use a special
>   .45-caliber, 110-grain metal cartridge with a 540-grain paper-patched bullet. It's fitted with double set triggers and a vernier sight. It's marked up to 1200 yards. This one shoots a mite further.

The scene in question can be viewed on youtube:

**So what exactly is the purpose of the double set triggers?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Reduced trigger pressure

At first I thought it was just Wild West [techno babble](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TechnoBabble) to fuel a [badass boast](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BadassBoast) about [his amazing weapon](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ICallItVera).

But lo and behold... there **is** a reason for it, as explained on [Wikipedia's page on triggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigger_(firearms)#Double_set_trigger).

> A set trigger allows a shooter to have a greatly reduced trigger pull (the resistance of the trigger) while maintaining a degree of safety in the field compared to having a conventional, very light trigger.
>
> [A] double set trigger accomplishes the same thing, but uses two triggers: one sets the trigger and the other fires the weapon. Set triggers are most likely to be seen on customized weapons and competition rifles where a light trigger pull is beneficial to accuracy.

So in short: it allows him to have a very light trigger pressure (which makes it easier to maintain accuracy) while at the same time not having his rifle go off at every bump, jolt and shove.

Comment: One would think such a sensitive weapon would be damaged by using it as a club...